# Xml To MYSQL Import using mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, xml, xml-parsing, mysql-workbench

i have written the below sql procedure to load data from xml to MYSQL table.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE pbadge (path varchar(255), node varchar(1000))
BEGIN
    declare xml_content text;
    declare v_row_index int unsigned default 0;   
    declare v_row_count int unsigned;  
    declare v_xpath_row varchar(50000); 

 START TRANSACTION;
    SAVEPOINT sp_order;

    set xml_content = load_file(path);

    -- calculate the number of row elements.   
    set v_row_count  = extractValue(xml_content, concat('count(', node, ')')); 

    -- loop through all the row elements    
    while v_row_index < v_row_count do                
        set v_row_index = v_row_index + 1;        
        set v_xpath_row = concat(node, '[', v_row_index, ']/@*');
        insert into badges values (
            extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[1]')),
            extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[2]')),
            extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[3]')),
            extractValue(xml_content, concat(v_xpath_row, '[4]'))


        );
    end while;
 COMMIT;
```

and my xml is like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<badges>

 <row Id="1" UserId="2" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T19:11:16.743" />

  <row Id="2" UserId="11" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T19:36:16.583" />

  <row Id="3" UserId="17" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T19:46:16.673" />

  <row Id="4" UserId="25" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T19:51:16.787" />

  <row Id="5" UserId="36" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T20:16:16.817" />

  <row Id="6" UserId="44" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T20:21:16.947" />

  <row Id="7" UserId="48" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T20:41:16.923" />

  <row Id="8" UserId="58" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T21:01:16.963" />

  <row Id="9" UserId="6" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-05T21:46:17.117" />

  <row Id="10" UserId="6" Name="Student" Date="2010-08-05T21:56:20.137" />
  ..
  ..
  ..
  ..

  <row Id="1000" UserId="647" Name="Student" Date="2010-08-05T21:56:20.137" />
```

i used below command in mysql command window,

```
call pbadge ('/home/naveen/Desktop/Badges.xml', '/badges/row');
```

it  works fine up to 852 row.

when i increase the xml row count above 852 nothing will be imported to table and the message displayed like below,

```
mysql> call pbadge ('/home/naveen/Desktop/Badges.xml', '/badges/row');
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

can any one help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: XML is dead. Long live JSON ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> " Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of
>   65,535 bytes. Storage engines may place additional constraints on this
>   limit, reducing the effective maximum row size... BLOB and TEXT
>   column contents are stored separately from the rest of the row.
>   [[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html)] "

This does not mean the TEXT data type can store anything without limits [[source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html#idm140282950012928)]:

- The `TEXT` data type has a maximum length of *65,535* (2<sup>`16`</sup> – 1) bytes (approx. 64KB).
- The `MEDIUMTEXT` data type has a maximum length of *16,777,215* (2<sup>`24`</sup> – 1) bytes (approx. 16MB)
- The `LONGTEXT` data type has a maximum length of *4,294,967,295* (2<sup>`32`</sup> – 1) bytes (approx. 4GB)

The effective maximum length is even less if the value contains multibyte characters.

---

> " it works fine up to 852 row... xml row count above 852 nothing will be imported to table"

That is because the other rows were never stored in the `xml_content` TEXT value as the number of characters in `Badges.xml` crossed the limit of 65,535 bytes (size > 64 KB).

The solution is to change the data type of `xml_content` from `TEXT` to `MEDIUMTEXT` if your XML file contents are lesser than 16MB (or *LONGTEXT* for larger contents lesser than 4GB). Change the declaration in your code to:

```
declare xml_content mediumtext;
```